# How to split string into chunks using regular expressions while keeping URI coded special characters together

Tags: regex, string, url, split, uri

Let's assume you have a string that you want to split into chunks having a maximum size of x characters. If you ignore new lines, a suitable regular expression would be .{1,x}

The problem I have is that I want to keep URI coded special characters like %20 together.

Example:

Hello%20world%20how%20are%20you%20today

Doing a "dumb" chunking with 5 character chunks, you end up with:

Hello
%20wo
rld%2
0how%
20are
%20yo
u%20t
oday

What I want to achieve is this:

Hello
%20wo
rld
%20ho
w%20a
re%20
you
%20to
day

Is this even possible with only regular expressions? I currently have a working solution with a loop that goes through each character and fills a bucket. If the bucket is full, it adds its content to an array of chunks and empties it. However, it also checks if the current character is a % and if the bucket would be able to hold 3 more characters (% plus the two hex digits). If it can, OK, otherwise it would push the content of the bucket in the chunks array and start with a fresh bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression to match all parts:

```
/(%[0-9A-F]{2}[^%]?[^%]?|[^%]%[0-9A-F]{2}[^%]?|[^%][^%]%[0-9A-F]{2}|[^%]{1,5})/
```

This basically lists all possible options to get at most five characters:

- **`%[0-9A-F]{2}[^%]?[^%]?`** – a percent-encoded octet followed by at most two non-`%` characters
- **`[^%]%[0-9A-F]{2}[^%]?`** – one non-`%` character, followed by a percent-encoded octet followed at most one non-`%` character
- **`[^%][^%]%[0-9A-F]{2}`** – two non-`%` characters followed by a percent-encoded octet
- **`[^%]{1,5}`** – one to five non-`%` characters

Comment: I wanted to avoid something like that because that works fine for 5 character chunks like in my example, but once you want like 6 character chunks, you would have to list all possible combinations for that. :(

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, stay with your working solution with a loop, its probably faster and ten times more readible.... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Guess you're right so I will stick to that, but I am still wondering if it's possible to do with only regular expressions and without listing all possible solutions (imagine doing chunking with 100 character large chunks).

Comment: @smares: Of course it is possible with regular expressions. Very little is not.